# What is the curl equivalent of wget -qO (wget -q -O)?

Tags: wget, curl

I need to run the following command in Red Hat Linux, but I don't have `wget` installed.

```sh
wget -q -O http://somepage/somefile.cgi | bash
```

What's the equivalent for `curl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
curl -s http://somepage/somefile.cgi | sh
```

EDIT: removed -O: Not needed as it's piping to the bash, as @gravity's comment mentions.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I never saw your edit and your original answer didn't work.  I ended up installing wget :p